# row expansion by column while manipulating other row based on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like so:

```
  column1  column2  column3
0       a        2        2
1       b        1        0
2       c        3        2
```

Where the value in column3 is necessarily <= the value in column2

I want to expand df to below based on the following rules:

```
  column1  column2  column3
0       a        1        1
1       a        1        1
2       b        1        0
3       c        1        1
4       c        1        1
5       c        1        0
```

1. every row is expanded into a number of rows equal to its value in column2
2. the value of column3 for expanded rows is equal to 1 if its index (relative to it's column1 grouping) is less than the original unexpanded row's value in column3.

For example:
See that the row with column1=a was expanded into 2 rows because its column2 value was equal to 2, and both the resulting expansion rows have a value of 1 in column3 because 0 < 2 and 1 < 2.

See that the row with column1=c was expanded into 3 rows because its column2 value was equal to 3, however, only the first 2 resulting expansion rows have a value of 1 in column3 (again: 0 < 2 and 1 < 2), however, the third expanded row gets a value of 0 for column3 because (yeah, yeah, yeah, this isn't kindergarten math) it is not true that 2 < 2.

What function can I use on a dataframe like the one first given, to get a result that looks like the second one?

Comment: Should column2 always be `1` in the result?

Comment: If there are no columns in the first dataframe where column2 is 0, then yes all column2 values in the expanded df should be 1. column2 in the expanded dataframe should never have a value greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `np.repeat` + `cumcount`

```
u = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, df.column2, axis=0), columns=df.columns)

u.assign(
  column2=1,
  column3=(u.column3 > u.groupby('column1').cumcount()).astype(int)
)
```

```
  column1  column2  column3
0       a        1        1
1       a        1        1
2       b        1        0
3       c        1        1
4       c        1        1
5       c        1        0
```

Comment: This looks like I want, let me test on a few df's and then I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I think, this is a merge problem

```
s1=df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.column2),['column1']].assign(column2=1).reset_index(drop=True)
s2=df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.column3),['column1']].assign(column3=1).reset_index(drop=True)
df=s1.assign(Key=s1.groupby(s1.column1).cumcount()).merge(s2.assign(Key=s2.groupby(s2.column1).cumcount()),how='left').fillna(0)
df

  column1  column2  Key  column3
0       a        1    0      1.0
1       a        1    1      1.0
2       b        1    0      0.0
3       c        1    0      1.0
4       c        1    1      1.0
5       c        1    2      0.0
```